# C++: Using std::cout with gcc on a mac osx

Tags: c++, macos

I'm new to C++ programming and I try to make my first exercise on a mac using gcc in the terminal.

Unfortunately, I can't compile because of issues related to iostream. With a simple program as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

 std::cout << "hello world";
 std::cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

it gives me the error:

```
error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
```

removing the cout << endl; line gives me these errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in cceBlyS2.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in cceBlyS2.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in cceBlyS2.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in cceBlyS2.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      __ZSt4cout$non_lazy_ptr in cceBlyS2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's evident that the iostream header is not properly linked. I tried "<"iostream.h">" and "iostream.h" with no success.

Does anybody has any hint that could help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You need to use `std::endl;` -- the entire standard library is in the `std` namespace. It also looks like you used `gcc` instead of `g++` on the command line. The latter automatically does the steps necessary to link C++ correctly.

Comment: Gratitude to you! Everything works now.
Thanks for helping a total newbie like me !

Comment: I'm just starting learning C++, all I can say is, Wow, I didn't know there was a difference between GCC and G++ (duh), saved my life. Thanks man.

Answer (score 7):

`endl;` falls under the `std` namespace

your 2 options are as follows:

1) declaring your namespace, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "hello world";
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

or using `std::endl;` e.g.

```
 std::cout << "hello world";
 std::cout << std::endl;
 return 0;
```

See which one suits you. I recommend 1) (Check that I didn't do `std::cout` because I've declared my namespace already) as it helps to reduce typing `std::` everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `std::endl;`. Or, better yet, make use of the handy `using` directive:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's less against the purpose of a namespace to `using namespace std::x;` for a given `x` that you need to access, rather than to bring the entire namespace into scope in one fell swoop.

Comment: @Chris: I disagree. While I would certainly avoid something like `using namespace std;` in a *header file*, I think it is perfectly fine inside a source file, especially a simple one like this. I see no reason to pollute the source file with `std::` all over the place unless it is absolutely necessary. I would also prefer to never re-use a name that was already used in the STL. Bringing in the whole namespace would let me catch such a mistake early.

Comment: @e.James: there's one minor problem with that: you don't know what's in the `std` namespace -- it can and does vary between implementations. You can have something work fine for an arbitrary length of time, and then quit working on a different (version of a) compiler. Admittedly, in *this* case, where the *only* name you're defining is `main`, there's not much that can go wrong -- but when/if you do any more than that, it's a whole different story.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I have to admit that I've never experienced such a thing. Do different implementations really have different public names in the `std` namespace?

Comment: @e.James:Yes, definitely. Just for one example, if you want POSIX compatibility, you *have* to define a fair number of names (some in standard headers) that aren't in the C or C++ standards.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be really an issue....Borland C++ and GCC/G++ follows the same protocol when declaring using namespace std (as far as I'm concerned). I don't know about other compilers but that's never been an issue so far.